# I want to stop this running after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript

- I tried using setTimeout(clearInterval(MY_INT, 10000) in the function olo() but it ran only once and stopped :/ Where could I put it or should I use for()?

There is no `<script src></script>` tag because I am using online editor. If you guys know how to make VScode like an online editor please suggest.
*

```
const btn = document.getElementById('Button');
const target = document.getElementById('here');

btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  
  
  function olo(){
  let loadingImage = document.createTextNode('**');
  target.appendChild(loadingImage);
    
  
  }

  const MY_INT = setInterval(olo ,1000)
})
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  
  <title>Loading...</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
   
    <button id='Button'>load</button>
    <h1 id='here'></h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The `10000` argument should be in `setTimeout`s parameters, but you have it in `clearInterval`.
2. You should not place it in the `olo` function, it should be right after you set the interval.
3. `setTimout` expects a callback, you have provided it a function call, change `clearInterval(MY_INT)` to an anonymous function (or any function, but NOT a function call). e.g. `() => clearInterval(MY_INT)`

Full cleanup of your code with the fixes above (i tweaked the timings slightly to make it easier to play with):

```js
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  function olo() {
    let loadingImage = document.createTextNode("*");
    target.appendChild(loadingImage);
  }

  const MY_INT = setInterval(olo, 500);
  setTimeout(() => clearInterval(MY_INT), 3000);
});
```

[Sandbox with fix](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-cloud-lccpc?file=/src/index.js:240-485)